# Remove extra brackets from JSON call in Integromat

Tags: arrays, json, make.com

I am running a HTTP call to bring back data in JSON format but this is bringing through an extra set of square brackets that is causing issues when i am trying to recognise the array.  See screen shots.

[image]

I can remove the extra set manually in a JSON editor but need to try and find a way of doing this automatically as part of my call.

I am running the call through Integromat and have looked at using Regex but couldn't find the correct code combinations.

Any help or advise much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the replace function and insert the brackets that need to be found using regex pattern making sure you denote the bracket at the starting position and the bracket at the end of the string to be replaced with emptystring

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't check "Parse Response" in HTTP Request module.
   That way Data will be returned as long text
2. Use "Text Parser"'s "Replace", look for ^[|]$ and replace it with emptystring. Make sure you check "Global Match", otherwise it will only do to the first match only=[

3.Then just Parse Json from parsed(replaced) text

I think this article will help.
https://medium.com/@petr.hnilica/json-in-integromat-how-to-create-an-array-from-collections-with-the-same-structure-2991b985e03e

Comment: You could also Iterate by keys() and use get(data; value(from Iterator)) to go through.